# json returned from CI REST API is failing jsonlint tests

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, rest

I have the following code in a codeigniter REST app (built using: https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver)

```
public function fullname_get()
{
   $fullname = array("fname"=>"john", "lname"=>"doe");
   $data["json"] = json_encode($fullname);
   $this->response($data["json"], 200);
}
```

When I call the API, this return json that looks like this:

```
{\"fname\":\"john\",\"lname\":\"doe\"}
```

The above json string fails http://jsonlint.com/ test because of the escape character "\". 
Just wondering how I can work around this? 
I'm building a REST api that is supposed to return json ... and I have to make sure it's legit json.

Thanks.

Comment: you've probably got `magic_quotes` enabled, which means your PHP install is horribly configured and/or hideously outdated.

Comment: You'll have to explain where the array comes from, that code produces valid JSON: http://3v4l.org/pQNYR

Comment: *"this produces json that looks like this"* No, it doesn't. My guess is that the extra backslashes are added by however you're outputting the JSON.

Comment: @T.J Crowder, good point.  I forgot to mention (sorry, head cold right now) that I'm using CI, and CI's REST libraries.  Big piece of info that I missed.. sorry guys.  Am going to log using log_message() the results of the json_encode

Comment: so it does look like the json is changed after i call $this->response().  I've also modified the title of the question to be more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 $fullname = array("fname"=>"john", "lname"=>"doe");
 $this->response($fullname, 200);//it sends data json format. You don't need to json encode it
```

You got that response because your data is json encoded twice

Comment: thanks.  I shouldn't have assumed that I would have to manually encode.

Answer (score 0):

It is legit JSON - and you didn't write a test ;)

```
{
    "fname": "john",
    "lname": "doe"
}
```

Please see the demo over at http://ideone.com/5IW1Ef

---

The class you are using does magical things:

`$this->response($this->db->get('books')->result(), 200);`

and based on the format specified on the URL the response data is converted to JSON. You don't have to do the JSON encoding.

Please read the examples provides here
https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver#responses

```
 $fullname = array("fname"=>"john", "lname"=>"doe");
 $this->response($fullname, 200);
```

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2--net-8814

Comment: hi there.  i just added some more details that really should have been in the first post.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: What you are doing is serializing already JSON to JSON again. 
`$this->response($data, 200);` Or what it is called on PHP.

Comment: Hmm, the response() method modifies your JSON. And it does way to much. https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/blob/master/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php#L445 My suggestion bypass that crap: two things are needed. A proper header indicating that it is a JSON response and the JSON itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to strip slashes, use this stripslashes(json_encode($fullname)). Full code mention below:

```
public function fullname_get()
{
   $fullname = array("fname"=>"john", "lname"=>"doe");
   $data["json"] = stripslashes(json_encode($fullname));
   $this->response($data["json"], 200);
}
```

I hope this will solve your issue.